# Расставьте знаки препинания и объясните их постановку

Tags: пунктуация, причастный-оборот

Уставшая от вечных приземленных разговоров Фрося решила посетить безолаберную недавно открывшуюся поставку амфотерного или не очень алюминия которому она была обязана жизнью еще со времен никогда не существовавшего крестового похода.

Нужна ли запятая после "разговоров"? Есть ли здесь обстоятельственный оттенок значения? Или возможны оба варианта?

Answer (score 1):

Если отвлечься от туманного смысла, то предложение будет выглядеть так:

*Уставшая от вечных приземленных разговоров, Фрося решила посетить безалаберную, недавно открывшуюся поставку амфотерного или не очень алюминия, которому она была обязана жизнью еще со времен никогда не существовавшего крестового похода.*

Здесь **две причины** для обособления причастного оборота:

а) дополнительное обстоятельственное значение причины: 
б) ограниченная сочетаемость оборота с именами собствеными.

Comment: "Безалаберную, недавно открывшуюся" (?!) Ну хотя бы так: "недавно открывшуюся безалаберную".

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что причастный оборот имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение (после того, как Фрося устала от вечных приземленных разговоров, она  решила что-то там посетить), и запятая нужна.

Примечания

1. Корректно: безалаберную (через *а*)
2. У меня немало сомнений по поводу осмысленности этого отрывка в целом.